# Indentation of Template Restrictions

Tags: emacs, d

Emacs [d-mode](https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/blob/master/d-mode.el) currently incorrectly indents template restrictions such as

```
auto f(T)(T x)
    if (is(T == struct))
{
}
```

as

```
auto f(T)(T x)
    if (is(T == struct))
    {
    }
```

Does anybody have any idea on where to start digging to fix this? Note that `d-mode` uses `cc-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `C-h f d-mode`, and it should say: `d-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in 'd-mode.el'.` Follow the `d-mode.el` link.

From searching for "indent" in that file, it looks like they just use whatever is defined in `cc-mode`. You can find out what function they use by running this in a d-mode buffer:

```
 C-h v indent-line-function
```

This shows they did just use `c-indent-line`. Perhaps a way to fix this is to try to detect this one case, and otherwise fallback on `c-indent-line`. Something like this (untested code, illustrative purposes only):

```
(defun d-indent-line ()
  (let* ((auto-if-curly 
          (save-excursion
            (back-to-indentation
             (when (looking-at "{")
               (forward-line -1)
               (back-to-indentation
                (when (looking-at "if")
                  (forward-line -1)
                  (back-to-indentation
                   (looking-at "auto")))))))))
    (if auto-if-curly
        (ident-line-to 0)
      (c-ident-line))))

(add-hook d-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local indent-line-function 'd-indent-line)))
```